# InstagramBasicDisplay PHP CallBack

Tags: php, instagram, access-token, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to access instagram user insights with [`InstagramBasicDisplay`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/).

However I am not sure how to implement the `callback` to grab the `code` which is necessary to get the `access token`.

I can get the user to sign in to instagram with the help of this [wrapper](https://github.com/espresso-dev/instagram-basic-display-php/blob/master/README.md).

```
$instagram = new InstagramBasicDisplay([
  'appId' => 'XXXXX',
  'appSecret' => 'XXXX',
  'redirectUri' => 'https://httpstat.us/200'
 ]);
echo "<a href='{$instagram->getLoginUrl()}'>Login with Instagram</a>";
```

In order to get the `access token`, I need to grab the `code`.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement the API call that exchanges the code for a token, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#step-5--exchange-the-code-for-a-token

Comment: FYI: There are no insights available with the Basic Display API; that is only a thing for business/creator accounts accessed via the Instagram Graph API.

Comment: @CBroe I have implemented the following with the graph API, I was wondering if I can achieve the same with the basic display api (If not all at least 1 or 2):

1. /insights?metric=audience_gender_age&period=lifetime"
2. /insights?metric=audience_city&period=lifetime
3. ?fields=business_discovery.username('.$this->instagram_user_name.'){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}

Comment: There are no insights, and what info you can get for user accounts, is documented here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your reply. Would you be able to show me how to get the code programatically as per the original post? Thank You!